# Extension on Collection and MutableCollection collide and are declared Redundant by Xcode

Tags: swift, swift4

I have a file in which I have 2 different extensions:

```
extension MutableCollection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index { }
extension Collection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {}
```

In the mutable one, I only have extensions that are mutable ( makes sense! right? ) and in Collection I have extensions that are common to both classes.

Problem is I get this warning from Swift Compiler:

> Redundant same-type constraint 'Self.Index' ==
>   'Self.Indices.Iterator.Element'

What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not that your two extension collide, you would get
the same warning with a single extension

```
extension Collection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index { }
```

The **short answer** is: Just remove the redundant constraints from your declarations:

```
extension MutableCollection { ... }
extension Collection { ... }
```

**Explanation:** Swift 3 did not allow to constrain associated
types. Even if `Indices.Iterator.Element == Index` was satisfied
for all concrete collections (Array, ArraySlice, Set, ...), the
language could not *require* it. That's why you had to add
this constraint to your extension if you needed it.

Swift 4 now allows to constrain associated types with a `where`
clause, see [SE-0142 Permit where clauses to constrain associated types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0142-associated-types-constraints.md).

The `Collection` protocol defines

```
associatedtype Indices : Sequence = DefaultIndices<Self>
         where Self.Index == Self.Indices.Element, ...
```

and the `Sequence` protocol defines

```
associatedtype Element where Self.Element == Self.Iterator.Element
```

So we always have the identities

```
Indices.Iterator.Element == Indices.Element == Index
```

and therefore you can remove those constraints from your code.